esbuild Include folder/file to the bundle
I am developing lambda function with serverless framework, that uses esbuild under the hood. This function is going to send emails, so i need to store templates along with ts code. The problem is that i need to take the folder with templates to the builded bundle, and i cannot find a esbuild configuration to do that.
I have tried a different esbuild options: --externals - no profit, --add-externals - didnt find a way to specify it in esbuild config in serverless.yml. GPT suggested a custom plugin implementation, but i hope there is a simple way of adding external folders to the bundle.

Does this answer your question? How to include static files into the lambda package with AWS SAM esbuild?

Thanks, looks like it, but i have ended up finding a plugin - library
esbuild-copy-static-files gives a plugin to implement that behavior. Also esbuild-plugin-copy does exactly same thing.
